# XSLT Select Only Nodes With Text in a Loop

Tags: xslt, xpath

I would like to select only nodes containing text nodes.  But when I test for text() parent nodes that contain child nodes with text get returned also.  I tried to check by 
string-length() but the parent nodes are returning a string length greater than 0.

In this scenario I would like to select only

```
SendDate
FirstName
LastName
Company
Street
City
State
Zip
```

Thanks

**XML**

```
<BusinessLetter>
    <Head>
        <SendDate>November 29, 2005</SendDate>
        <Recipient>
            <Name Title="Mr.">
                <FirstName>Joshua</FirstName>
                <LastName>Lockwood</LastName>
            </Name>
            <Company>Lockwood &amp; Lockwood</Company>
            <Address>
                <Street>291 Broadway Ave.</Street>
                <City>New York</City>
                <State>NY</State>
                <Zip>10007</Zip>
                <Country>United States</Country>
            </Address>
        </Recipient>
    </Head>
</BusinessLetter>
```

**XSL**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="//*[text()]">
            <xsl:if test="text()">
                    <Match>
                        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>:
                        <xsl:value-of select="string-length(text())"/>
                    </Match>
                    <br />
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
BusinessLetter: 2
Head: 3
SendDate: 17
Recipient: 4
Name: 5
FirstName:6
LastName:8
Company:19
Address:5
Street:17
City:8
State:2
Zip:5
Country:13
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation and a simple, most unobtrusive fix to your code.

Answer (score 3):

You are experience a problem with white space only text nodes...

Solution preserving white space only text nodes (better when processing (X)HTML ):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="*[text()[normalize-space()]]">
        <Match>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(),
                                         ' : ',
                                         string-length(normalize-space()))"/>
        </Match>
        <br />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<Match>SendDate : 17</Match>
<br />
<Match>FirstName : 6</Match>
<br />
<Match>LastName : 8</Match>
<br />
<Match>Company : 19</Match>
<br />
<Match>Street : 17</Match>
<br />
<Match>City : 8</Match>
<br />
<Match>State : 2</Match>
<br />
<Match>Zip : 5</Match>
<br />
<Match>Country : 13</Match>
<br />
```

Answer (score 2):

Good question. I spent a few days looking for an answer.

```
<xsl:value-of select="string-length(normalize-space(text()[1]))" />
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem is caused by the fact that the white-space-only text nodes are also considered.

**Solution**:

**Include this global (best place is before any `<xsl:template>`) directive**:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

This instructs the XSLT processor to strip-off the white-space-only text-node children of any (*) element in the XML document.

**So, your fixed transformation now is**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="//*[text()]">
            <xsl:if test="text()">
                <Match>
                    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>:                         
                    <xsl:value-of select="string-length(text())"/>
                </Match>
                <br />
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**and when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<BusinessLetter>
    <Head>
        <SendDate>November 29, 2005</SendDate>
        <Recipient>
            <Name Title="Mr.">
                <FirstName>Joshua</FirstName>
                <LastName>Lockwood</LastName>
            </Name>
            <Company>Lockwood &amp; Lockwood</Company>
            <Address>
                <Street>291 Broadway Ave.</Street>
                <City>New York</City>
                <State>NY</State>
                <Zip>10007</Zip>
                <Country>United States</Country>
            </Address>
        </Recipient>
    </Head>
</BusinessLetter>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<Match>SendDate:                         
                    17
</Match><br><Match>FirstName:                         
                    6
</Match><br><Match>LastName:                         
                    8
</Match><br><Match>Company:                         
                    19
</Match><br><Match>Street:                         
                    17
</Match><br><Match>City:                         
                    8
</Match><br><Match>State:                         
                    2
</Match><br><Match>Zip:                         
                    5
</Match><br><Match>Country:                         
                    13
</Match><br>
```

Comment: +1 Good answer. And the right choice in general, except when white space only text node are meaningful: processing mixed content in general and XHTML in particular.

Comment: @Alejandro: Yes, but in this case the document is not XHTML.